# Guest OS issue in Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v

My company have one domain controller(win2008 R2) & One Hyper-V Host(win2008 R2 and join in the domain,one network adapter for host management and another one for VM switch).

The issue now is:It is very slow when joining the guest(win 2008 R2) to domain! After joining the domain, when i try to add permission to folder or access the other server from network it will come out the below error msg while ping to domain controller will be interrupted!
Any suggestion? The Ping will be OK if you never do any other things on guest OS! Thanks!
[image]

Comment: How does it work frmo the host? I run a lot of also heavy duty VM's, and I dont ahve the issue ever. I would suggest a driver / caling / swith issue somewhere. Especially "Destination host unreachable" indicates at least an ARP resolution issue which just should not happen. Is the network hopelessly overlaoded?

Comment: Hi, this only happen on guest OS only. From the host and other server,all is OK.

Comment: This is funny. Never seen this before. Is the network driver crurent on the host? using enlightment, or the classical / legacy adapter?

Comment: Hi Using enlightment! There are five adapters in host, but only using one adapter as VM switch and it will work fine! if using another one from balance four adapters as VM switch, it will be like the issue i post? Is it the adpater issue? Even though i replace new PCI adpater,the issue still come out? I can not understand!

Comment: Me neither. I wuold say somthing is really fishy on the adapter side, host side. DO you use teaming? Nice high end adapter (Intel)? What adapters, what driver versions?

Comment: Hi, this is in testing environment,so i only use normal desktop 1gb adapter (eg: tp-link TG-3269 & dlink DGE-528T )using the newest drivers. i think i can't afford like this as moving on to production environment.

Comment: Ah yes. Let's jsut say that I have seen a TON of issues with cheap desktop adapters left and right, even on server boards with "server on board stuff". Just ordered my first quad port intel card for about 400 USD to finally get rid of the crap. I would suggest at least getting intel cards, those have good drivers. Could be a driver issue.